# If a "heavy" function located in a header file is not marked with 'inline', where its code is compiled to?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, inline

I already know that, when I put the definition of a member function into a header and mark the function as `inline`, the code in the function gets inlined into any place where the function is called out of a .cpp file, so when it comes to a compiled binary, I know where the function's code is located -- within the compiled code of any .cpp file that depends on it. But what happens if I don't mark a function in a header with `inline` and the function's body is large enough to make the compiler choose not to inline it? In the context of a static/dynamic library the function's class belongs to, where does the function's code is compiled to? Or is it not compiled at all and the final destination for the function's code is a compiled .cpp of a client of the library? If it's the latter case, does the function's code still gets inlined even if I didn't mark it with `inline` (because its code was too "heavy")? And finally, is MSVC compiler's behavior in this case differs from the GCC's one?

And sure, I realize that putting member functions I want to be inlined into .h file (or .inl file) and "heavy" function into .cpp file would make things crystal clear, but I would really like to avoid breaking a class' implementation across files, hence is the interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mark a function `inline` you're not forcing the compiler to inline it at every place it's called, you're just telling it that that the definition is inline and it should expect duplicate copies in different compilation units. The actual code will be compiled at least once for every compilation unit where you include the header and call the function.

If you don't declare it inline, the linker should complain about multiple definitions of the function, even if those definitions are identical.

Comment: Would the linker complain if the header files had appropriate `#ifndef`/`#define` to prevent repetitive inclusion (they do already)?

Comment: @DesmondHume, the include guards only prevent the file from being included multiple times in the same .cpp. They don't keep the file from being included once in every .cpp. Thus every .cpp could potentially contain a copy of the function, and the compiled binaries would as well. When the linker consolidates the binary files it will notice the duplicates.

Comment: Note: This does not prevent the linker from removing duplicate version across compilation units.

Answer (score 4):

It's compiled directly into each translation unit that includes your header. If there is more than one such file you violate the one definition rule and make your program malformed.

If you really want to put all your code in one file, put it in the header and mark the function inline. It's only a suggestion so if the function is too big, the compiler won't inline it anyway, it will be compiled exactly like a non-inline function. But note that this is *not* canonical C++ because it can drastically increase compilation times. The normal pattern is in fact to separate the interface (headers) from the implementation (source file(s)). If the compiler decides to not inline the function, it will be written into the compiled object file for each translation unit that includes the header, and the linker will be required to pick an instance from one of the object files, throwing away the rest (since the code for each version is identical).

Comment: "if the function is too big, the compiler won't inline it anyway" -- great, it's what my question is actually about: where does the code of such functions compile to?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, "inline" is merely a "request" to the compiler - nothing more.

Moreover, there's nothing preventing you from declaring a standalone "static" function in a header.  At which point the SAME binary code gets DUPLICATED in every object file whose source file #include's the header.

Guess what - the same thing can happen with inline functions :)

Personally, I like to see *nothing* but class and struct definitions, typedefs, constants, function prototypes  ... and externs ... in a header file.